# xcode UI elements constraints layout

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.5

I am new to Mac OS and  Xcode , i am having a problem with UI elements layout, the elements on the emulator appears different from it when i put it on view , check the photo below please, is it something about auto layout ?

[image: layout problem]

Comment: You likely need to set constraints on the positioning of elements to prevent the label from being able to move in relation to your text inputs.

Comment: and how to set that constrains please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `constraints` and `auto layout` functionality of iOS 6.

Please check this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2) for a good start.

Comment: thank you a lot , it helps me , but why they down vote to my question?

Comment: don't know , i think because you didn't mentioned what you have tried.(+1) from me, for asking a good question with image. I din't see any question in SO related to contraints issues :)

Answer (score 1):

Apple provides a short introduction to constraints in the tutorial "[Your Second iOS App](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/SecondiOSAppTutorial/CreatingAddView/CreatingAddView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011318-CH6-SW11)"

In short, when you create elements, some constraints are created automatically, and will help automatically space your items. Others are not automatically created and you create them by selecting an element and using the size inspector or pin constraints to prevent collisions and allow rotation to automatically reposition elements.

Comment: thanks a lot , i hope i could accept more than one answer ,+1 for u